# Can I just replace a 20 amp breaker in the box with a 30 amp if my wire is 10-2.?

Tags: electrical

I have a inground pool and I just installed a jacuzzi that runs on a 20 amp breaker in the house and 20 amp glass fuses in the garage where the pools gfi is. When I turn on the jacuzzi, it trips the breaker in the house panel. Can I just replace the 20 amp breaker inside with a single pole 30 if I have 10 -2 wire running out to the garage? Then just install a new small 30 amp box with individual breakers for the pool and Jacuzzi?

Comment: Increasing breaker size because of tripping is usually a bad idea.  There is a but.  What does the instructions for the jacuzzi say you need for a breaker?  Are the pool and jacuzzi on the same breaker in the house?

Comment: If you edit your question with more information, might get a better answer than no.  Is the circuit 240 or 120 volts?  What is the ampage for the jacuzzi and pool pump?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go back and review the installation instructions for the jacuzzi.  It will tell you what it needs for a circuit.  You need to follow the instructions.

It's possible it was incorrectly installed in the first place.

If it is installed correctly and it's still tripping, then what remains is either someone has tapped the circuit for additional appliance loads, which are *together with the jacuzzi* overloading the circuit, hardly a surprise. The answer is to remove the offending power stealers and get them their own circuit.

(your subpanel plan might be one way to do that, getting 30A out of the wire despite the devices having 15/20A circuits as they might require).

The last possibility is the jacuzzi has an electrical fault.  Is it wise to use a water appliance which is known to have an electrical fault? I'd say no.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - very likely not.  Electricians rarely upsize wire for the fun of it, so if you have 10-2 on a 20A breaker, there's probably a reason for it that shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: Agree. You will have to examine the entire circuit  and make sure there's no #12 AWG anywhere.